# How to set an environment variable via Zsh from within a Swift script

Tags: swift, shell, zsh

Consider the following Swift script (`Shell.swift`):

```
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Foundation

func shell(_ command: String) {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    print(output)
}
```

If I add this line to it (at the end):

`shell("date")`

... and invoke it from my Terminal like so:

`$ ./Shell.swift`

The output is:

`Sun Jan 26 11:35:52 CET 2020`

If I add this line:

`shell("echo $LANG")`

The output is:

`en_US.UTF-8`

It works as expected.

Now if I add these lines:

```
shell("export MY_VAR=123")
shell("echo $MY_VAR")  // Nothing is printed out
```

Is there a way for doing that?

> How to set an environment variable via Zsh from within a Swift script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every invocation of your `shell()` function spawns a new Z shell, and setting an environment variable in the first invocation does not affect the environment of the second invocation.

Here are some options: You can set the environment within the zsh script that is to be executed. Example:

```
shell("date")
// Sun Jan 26 11:56:25 CET 2020

shell("export TZ=UTC ; date")
// Sun Jan 26 10:56:25 UTC 2020
```

Or you can set `task.environment` by adding specified environment variables to the default environment:

```
func shell(_ command: String, addEnvironment: [String: String]? = nil) {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]
    if let addEnv = addEnvironment {
        var currentEnv = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
        for (key, value) in addEnv {
            currentEnv[key] = value
        }
        task.environment = currentEnv
    }

    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    print(output)
}
```

Example:

```
shell("date", addEnvironment: ["TZ": "UTC"])
// Sun Jan 26 10:56:25 UTC 2020
```